# Remove view hold by getview() in an adapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

```
//////////////////////  
MyAdapter mMyAdapter;  
GridView mGridView;  
mGridView.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);  
mMyAdapter.setData(anyDataList);  
isListView = true;  

/////////// When click on button [named: SwitchView] ///////////  
if (isListView) {  
    isListView = false;  
    mGridView.setNumColumns(1);    
    mMyAdapter.setIsListView(true);  
    mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
} else {  
    isListView = true;  
    mGridView.setNumColumns(1);  
    mMyAdapter.setIsListView(false); 
    mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
}  

/////////// Adapter Class Defination ///////////  
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {  
    List<MyClass> mData;  
    boolean mIsListView;  

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (mIsListView) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        } else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, parent, false);
        }
        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
        // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(mData.getName());
        return rowView;
    }

    public void setData(List<MyClass> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public void setIsListView(boolean isListView) {
        mIsListView = isListView;
    }
}
```

/////////// What is my requirement ///////////
When I clicked on button SwitchView, Adapter should inflate either list_view or grid_view layouts.

/////////// Problem ///////////
In my case, data in adapter is same, but it's view is changing. But when I clicked on button SwitchView, then I got some unexcepted result. GridView shows both type of layout (list_view and grid_view). In some list position it shows layout "list_view" and in some other position it shows layout "grid_view".

/////////// Cause ///////////
This problem is coming because getView() holds the old view.

/////////// Solution ///////////
In place of using mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), should instantiate new mMyAdapter. But I want to know if there is another solution. I don't want to instantiate new Adapter.

Comment: please post full code how are values of isListView and mIsListView determined

Comment: I have updated my code. Let assume that it will works like toggle button. isListView and mIsListView changed everytime the button get clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a new adapter. Just need to leverage the adapter's view type.  In your MyAdapter class, override the view type count.  Eg:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Next override the `getItemViewType` method to return whether it's a grid or list.  Eg:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mIsListView ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Finally, in the `getView` method, check a positions item type in order to determine which layout to inflate.  You can then proceed to populate the view. Eg:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        } else {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, parent, false);
        }

        // configure view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    } 

    holder.text.setText(mData.getName());
    return rowView;
}
```

Note, this example demonstrates just using the view type to determine which view to inflate. If you're data has to populate each view type differently, then you'll also need to use the view type to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid using view holder  but then its going to affect the performance of list. I believe switching layout is not just dataset change its the whole layout change task for inflater so either instantiate new Adapter or avoid using view holder there seems no other way.